# Arguments Array in JavaScript (ES5)

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Maybe that is not my evening :/ Very simple thing, I want to give an array as parameter to a function as arguments array:

```
function add() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The following works:

```
console.log(add(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

But if I fill an array and give it as parameter, like:

```
var myNumbers = [];
for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
    myNumbers.push(i);
}
console.log(add(myNumbers));
```

I get trouble. I think, I miss something important about the `arguments` array.

How should I change the add function, so that both possibilities can work with it?

Comment: In second case myNumbers is an array(so try accessing as arguments[0]) in add function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
add(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

...you're calling `add` with a series of *discrete* (separate) arguments, and each of them shows up in the `arguments` pseudo-array, 1 at `arguments[0]`, 2 at `arguments[1]`, etc.

But here:

```
add(myNumbers);
```

...you're calling `add` with **one** argument, which is an array. That's at `arguments[0]`.

You'll want to write `add` to fit how you want to call it. If you want to call it with discrete arguments, write it the way you have. If you want to write it to accept an array, have it take a single argument and loop through that (which will be the array):

```
function add(args) {
    //       ^------------- the one argument
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        sum += args[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you want to handle *both*, you could use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) (newish, but shimmable) to check the first argument to see if it's an array and either use it if it is or use `arguments` if it isn't:

```
function add(args) {
    if (!Array.isArray(args)) {
        args = arguments;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        sum += args[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

Side note: `arguments` isn't an array, it's just *array-like*.

Comment: thank you, how should I modify the add function, so that both works?

Comment: @Lonely: You could detect whether the first argument is an array via [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) (that's newish, but easily shimmed for older browsers). Then either use the first argument, or `arguments`. I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

The `arguments` object is an array-like object, but it is not an array. It is used to represent all arguments passed into the function. You have only passed in one value into the function, so your array is actually at index 0 of the `arguments` object.

However, there really isn't much point using `arguments` here unless you need to dynamically handle things without defining an explicit API. Just declare your parameter in the `add` function.

```
function add(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you want to support both cases, as per your comment, you can do something like:

```
function add() {
    var arr = [].concat.apply([], arguments);
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**Explanation of**
`[].concat.apply([], arguments)`

- `[].` is shorthand for `Array.prototype` because it's an empty array.
- `concat` merges two or more arrays together, or an array and values to go into the array.
- `arguments` is not an array, but many of the prototype functions will work on it, due to some array-like characteristics of the object - indexed items and the `length` property.
- `apply` calls a function with a given context (the `this` binding) and any number of arguments. In this case we still want to use the array as `this` value to be able to call `concat`, followed by all the arguments we passed into `add`. The result is simply all arguments as a proper array.

Comment: thank you, how should I modify the add function, so that both works?

Comment: @Lonely  See the updated answer which would handle both cases.

Comment: is that 'var arr = [].concat.apply([], arguments);' cross browser compatible?

Comment: Yes, it's just shorthand for `Array.prototype.concat`.

Comment: ES6 provides `Array.from(arguments);`

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for both situation :

```
function add() {
    var arr= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    arr = [].concat.apply([], arr);

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Also simple solution for sum :

```
 function add() {
        var arr= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        arr = [].concat.apply([], arr);

        return arr.reduce(function(f, s){return f + s;}, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
add.apply(null, [1,2,3])
```